# listview_onitemcommand is not firing

Tags: asp.net

my code is

```
protected void ListView2_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "forallow"))
    {

        string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
        string scrapid = commandArgs[0];
        string uid = commandArgs[1];
        string imgname = commandArgs[2];
        int cat = Convert.ToInt32(scrapid);
        int sho = Convert.ToInt32(uid);

        string query2 = "update request set status='allow' where request_id='" + cat + "'and shop_id=" + sho + ";update advertisement set imagename='" + imgname + "',shop_id='" + sho + "' where adver_id=" + cat;
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, connection);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (rows > 0)
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('permission granted');</script>");
        }
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        string msgg = "insert into messages(message,shop_id) values('Permission is granted for category id ''" + cat + "' ,'" + sho + "')";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(msgg, connection);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        productfill();

    }


}
```

and html code is

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" OnItemDeleting="ListView2_ItemDeleting" OnItemCommand="ListView2_OnItemCommand">
            <LayoutTemplate>  
            <table runat="server" class="TableCSS">  
                <tr runat="server" class="TableHeader"> 
                    <td runat="server">Advertisement ID</td>  
                    <td runat="server">Advertisement Plan</td> 
                     <td runat="server">Shop ID</td>

                     <td runat="server">Permission</td>

                </tr>  
                <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server">  
                </tr>  
                <tr runat="server" class="TablePager">  
                    <td runat="server" colspan="3">  
                        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">  
                            <Fields>  
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField   
                                    ButtonType="Button"   
                                    ShowFirstPageButton="true"  
                                    ShowPreviousPageButton="false"  
                                    ShowNextPageButton="true"  
                                    ButtonCssClass="PagerButtonCSS"  
                                    />  
                                <asp:NumericPagerField   
                                    NumericButtonCssClass="NumericButtonCSS"  
                                    NextPreviousButtonCssClass="NextPreviousButtonCSS"  
                                    CurrentPageLabelCssClass="CurrentPageLabelCSS" 

                                    />  
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField   
                                    ButtonType="Button"  
                                    ShowNextPageButton="false"  
                                    ShowLastPageButton="true"  
                                    ButtonCssClass="PagerButtonCSS"  
                                    />  
                            </Fields>  
                        </asp:DataPager>  
                    </td>  
                </tr>  
            </table>  
        </LayoutTemplate>  
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" 
            style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    NO RECORD FOUND.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate>  
            <tr class="TableData">  
                 <td>  

                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"request_id")%>'>
                            </asp:Label>

                </td>  
                <td>  

                            <asp:Label ID="lblcat" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"adver_plan")%>'>
                            </asp:Label>

                </td>  

                <td>  

                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"shop_id")%>'>
                            </asp:Label>

                </td>  

                <td> <%-- ValidationGroup="cho" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"request_id")+","+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"shop_id")+","+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"message")%>'--%>

                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Allow" Width="45px" CommandName="forallow" ValidationGroup="cho" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"request_id")+","+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"shop_id")+","+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"message")%>'/><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Deny" Width="45px" ValidationGroup="2" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return deleteConfirm();"/>

                </td>  


            </tr>                  
        </ItemTemplate>  
         <EditItemTemplate>

         </EditItemTemplate>  

        </asp:ListView>
```

plz make this solve as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Where is your OnClick event? What is going to make this event fire? If this is all of your code then it will never fire. Recheck your code and make sure you show it all to us.